# directives angular js2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal, component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthDirective } from '../utils/auth.directive';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientService } from '../utils/http-client.service';
import { BaseAddressService } from '../utils/base-address.service';
import { AuthService, ClienteLogado } from '../utils/auth.service';
import {ModalUtilComponent} from '../utils/modal-util-component';

@Component({
templateUrl: './carrinho.component.html',
directives: [ Router, ModalUtilComponent ],

})
```

Pessoal qnd eu vou carrear o component que tem como função retornar uma modal, ele não está aceitando minha diretiva e esta retornando o seguinte erro.

```
/src/app/carrinho/carrinho.component.ts (11,5): Argument of type '{ templateUrl: string; directives: typeof ModalUtilComponent[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'.
```

O que pode estar acontecendo de errado ?

desde já muito obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

Nas últimas versões do Angular, você não define mais o directives no @Component.

Agora você declara suas diretivas no seu @ngModule. Por exemplo:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    ModalUtilComponent
  ]
})
```

Outra coisa, eu não sei o que exatamente você está tentando fazer, mas o Router não é uma diretiva, e sim um serviço que precisa ser injetado na sua diretiva, da uma olhadinha [aqui](https://angular.io/guide/router).